MLE and non closed-form solutions - how to see or proof it?
I can't really wrap my head around non closed-form solutions for MLE. In the lectures we did not go deeper into it, it was just assumed to be given that some log-likelihoods (or rather score functions) can't be solved for their respective parameters.
If we for example model binary responses with a logistic regression:

$y_i \sim Ber(\pi_i)$
$\pi_i = P(y_i=1) = h(\eta_i) = E(y_i) = \frac{exp(\eta_i)}{1+exp(\eta_i)}$
$\eta_i = g(\pi_i)= log(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i$

From this we would get:

$ \ell(\beta) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}[y_ilog(\pi_i) + (1-y_i)log(1-\pi_i)]$
$s(\beta) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial\eta_i}{\partial\beta} \frac{\partial\pi_i}{\partial\eta_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_i} \ell_i(\beta)$ $\leftarrow$ (If I am not mistaken)

Which part of the derivatives of $s(\beta)$ are not computable and how can I see or even prove it?

The derivatives are always computable in closed form. What's sometimes not possible is finding in closed form the parameter values which would make that gradient equal to zero. It's hard to know when it isn't possible, and sometimes someone finds a way to solve something which was previously not thought possible.

Your logistic regression example is a good example. There is no closed form solution in that case which is why we need the likelihood and the gradient. Note that a closed form solution and a computable-numerical solution are not the same thing.

@JohnMadden Thank you, but now I still have this empty feeling of not knowing. :D

@mlofton Thanks, do you have a recommended reading where this topic is explained in more detail? It seems that I just don't know that a closed form solution and a computable-numerical solution are not the same thing.

Hi BlankerHans: I bet you do know and it's just the terminology thats confusing you. Let me write a quick, short example in the answer and that should clear it up.

@BlankerHans welcome to the club!

BlankerHans: I wrote something in the answer but didn't emphasize that a purchase of both John's text ( I think its called Applied Regression and Linear Statistics Models )  and the companion ( CAR ) is strongly recommended. Buying the companion without the text is okay but it would be better to have both.  His books don't get the hype of some others but I remember reading them maybe 10-15 years ago and wondering why ?

Take the standard classical OLS model:
$$ \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\beta} \mathbf{X} + \epsilon $$
where $\mathbf{\beta}$ is a vector and $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix. There is a closed form solution for $\mathbf{\beta}$ under the model assumptions of OLS. The closed form solution for the estimate of ${\beta}$ is:
(1) $$ \hat{\beta} = \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{X}^{\prime}\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y}  $$
But, suppose that it wasn't possible to derive this closed form solution. For example, the logistic regression example that you provided is such a case.
Then, an alternative to the closed form solution of the OLS case is to calculate $\mathbf{\beta}$ using a numerical optimization scheme. I will avoid explaining the details behind the typical numerical optimization scheme here but they are reasonably straightforward.  John Fox's CAR ( companion to applied regression ) book has a nice section on numerical computing and optimization in R. The more gory details on optimization without regard to statistics are in any decent numerical optimization text say Nocedal and Wright.
Continuing with the numerical solution for the OLS case: Note that
one wants to minimize the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{\epsilon_{i}}^2$ through the use of an iterative optimization algorithm such as BFGS. ( Obviously, for this case, when the derivative of the summation is calculated, one gets a linear relation because there is a closed form solution but that's not important. We're just doing this to show that a numerical estimate is possible )
The important thing to understand is that, given the data, it is possible to minimize the sum through the use of a numerical algorithm and this would result in a numerical estimate of $\beta$. Fortunately, in the OLS case, the numerical result will be equal ( upto roundoff ) to the closed form estimate (1) for $\beta$.
So, I hope that this helps to iron out the difference between a closed form solution and a numerical solution. Oh, since I glossed over the details of the numerical solution,  I would strongly recommend going through John Fox's CAR book ( it's a companion to his text ) and working through some of the examples in R. In fact, IIRC, he happens to have a detailed example on logistic regression.  All the best.

Thank you very much. I will have a look into the mentioned literature. :)

you're welcome. I hope that you're able to obtain john's books.
